# Dispatch change on react-select doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've two react-select custom components used in react-redux form. Once I change a select on a select field, I need to clear the value of other select field component. dispatch(change) didn't help on this.

```
<Field name='towerNo' onChange={this.handleTowerChange} disabled={this.state.isTower} selectedValue={''} label='Tower' component={SearchBox} validate={[]} data={this.state.towers} selectkey={'towerName'} />

<Field name='floorNo' onChange={this.handleFloorChange} disabled={this.state.isFloor} selectedValue={''} label='Floor' component={SearchBox} validate={[]} data={this.state.floors} selectkey={'floorNumber'} />
```

Comment: can you post some code which helps us in identifying if something went wrong?

Comment: on the change of field towerNo, i always need to  clear the selected value (displaying value) of floorNo field.

Comment: Please edit your original post with code. These comments are pretty unreadable.